# How to handle Exception occuring when returning StreamingResponseBody from RestController

Tags: spring, rest, web

I have implemented a Spring Rest Controller that streams back large files using the StreamingResponseBody.  However, these files are coming from another system and there is the potential for something to go wrong while streaming them back. When this occurs I am throwing a custom Exception (MyException). I am handling the exception in an @ExceptionHandler implementation which is below.  I am attempting to set the response httpstatus and error message but I am always receiving http status 406.  What is the proper way to handle errors/exceptions while returning a StreamingResponseBody?

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    public void handleParsException( MyException exception, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(),exception.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem out.  The client was only accepting the file type as an acceptable response.  Therefore, when returning an error in the form of an html page I was getting httpstatus 406.  I just needed to tell the client to accept html as well to display the message.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle all errors in the same way. There are many options.

I prefer next:

#### Controller Advice

It is a good idea to have an entity to send a generic error response, an example:

```
public class Error {

 private String code;
 private int status;
 private String message;

 // Getters and Setters

}
```

Otherwise, to handle exceptions you should create a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and then create methods annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` and the exception or exceptions (it could be more than one) you want to handle. Finally return `ResponseEntity<Error>` with the status code you want.

```
public class Hanlder{

  @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
   public ResponseEntity<?> handleResourceNotFoundException(MyException
myException, HttpServletRequest request) {

     Error error = new Error();
     error.setStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value()); //Status you want
     error.setCode("CODE");
     error.setMessage(myException.getMessage());

     return new ResponseEntity<>(error, null, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
  }

  @ExceptionHandler({DataAccessException.class, , OtherException.class})
   public ResponseEntity<?> handleResourceNotFoundException(Exception
exception, HttpServletRequest request) {

     Error error = new Error();
     error.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_ERROR.value()); //Status you want
     error.setCode("CODE");
     error.setMessage(myException.getMessage());

     return new ResponseEntity<>(error, null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_ERROR);
  }
}
```

Other ways:

#### Annotate exception directly

Other way is annotating directly the excetion with the status and the reason to return:

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.CONFLICT, reason="Error with StreamingResponseBody") 
 public class MyError extends RuntimeException {
     // Impl ...
 }
```

#### Exception Handler in a specific controller

Use a method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` in a method of a `@Controller` to handle `@RequestMapping` exceptions:

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
                  reason="Error with StreamingResponse Body") 
  @ExceptionHandler(MyError.class)
  public void entitiyExists() {
  }
```

Comment: The problem is not necessarily with handling of exceptions as the method I wrote above is being called when an exception is being thrown.  However,  I am  setting the HttpStatus and  message in the response in my @ExceptionHandler but the client always receives 406 - Not acceptable.  I am wondering if since a response is already in the process of being written back, if setting info on the response object passed into the exception handler is not really being utilized and returned to the client in this situation. I will create a rudimentary example that I can post that demonstrates the problem.